# SQL Query with single quotes retrieves no record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am currently fetching a dataset from following query `select * from TableName WHERE ColumnName ='values''s'` query executes without any error and return dataset was empty rows. When i execute the same in SQL Worksheets it return data

> Following code for ref.

```
string sqlQuery = "select * from TableName WHERE Name ='McNaught''s'";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What is the actual value that you want to include in the where condition?

Comment: in where i included ColumnName = 'McNaught''s and Fertilizers'

Comment: Do you want query a fixed sql or dynamic one(concatenating some C# string)?

Comment: The best way is to use input in parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: Lei Yang, Its a dynamic query where as TableName, ColumnName and Value is passed dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
string sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Name ="McNaught\'s"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you need to provide Escape Sequence before the second `'` so that compiler can distinguish between the previous apostrophe. Try this.

```
string sqlQuery = "select * from TableName WHERE Name ='McNaught'\'s'";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work with `\` escape sequence.

```
string sqlQuery = "select * from TableName WHERE Name ='McNaught\"s'";
```